# How to catch Mysql::Error exception in the application controller in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

Am upgrading Rails 2.1.1 to rails 2.3.8. Previously i was able to catch Mysql::Error in the rescue_action_in_public method defined in application_controller. After upgrading to 2.3.8 version, the 'rescue_action_in_public' is not being called at all. What should i do to catch the Mysql::Error exception in my application controller.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :deny_access` and then make a method `def deny_access; flash[:error] = "not this time"; redirect_to root_url; end`

Whether rescue_action_in_public did more, i don't know.

Comment: the control doesnt come to the application_controller at all. It goes to the function failsafe_response and throws a FAILSAFE exception.